# Redux dispatch in useEffect isn't syncronous

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-navigation

I want to navigate to App screen or Auth screen, depending on the isUser prop after fetching it from the server and updating the redux store.

My first component `AuthLoading.js` which looks like this:

```
const AuthLoading = (props) => {
  const isUser = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.isUserExists);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const token = await TokensHandler.getTokenFromDevice();
    dispatch(isTokenExists(token));
    props.navigation.navigate(isUser ? "App" : "Auth");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

My `authActions.js` looks like this:

```
export const isTokenExists = (token) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return HttpClient.get(ApiConfig.IDENTITY_PORT, "api/identity", {
      userId: token,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      dispatch({
        type: IS_USER_EXISTS,
        payload: response,
      });
    });
  };
};
```

My `authReducer.js` looks like this:

```
const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {    
    case IS_USER_EXISTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isUserExists: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And the store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
};

export default configureStore;
```

Unfortunately, the code inside `AuthLoading.js` isn't asynchronous, and isn't waiting for the updated isUser value and running the next line without it.

I've tried to .then after dispatch which still doesn't work.
I've tried changing async states and still couldn't find the problem.
I have no idea how to fix this.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another `useEffect` hook that runs when `isUser` changes and navigate inside it.

This `useEffect` runs once the component mounts and every time `isUser` changes, so `someCondition` can be anything that determines whether the navigation should happen or not.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(someCondition) {
      props.navigation.navigate(isUser ? "App" : "Auth");
    }
    
}, [isUser]); // add all required dependencies
```

Comment: That's still not working, the second useEffect as you specified is running before the first useEffect(the one with the dispatch) finishes.

Comment: @Alon You can just add an if statement and only navigate when a condition is met.

Comment: .@RameshReddy can you please specify where exactly? after dispatching?

Comment: @Alon Updated my answer.

Comment: It's working!! basically i've added another state to the store called "isDoneFetching" which it's starting value was false. When I finished fetching i dispatched an action and updated it and then on the second useEffect i wrote [isDoneFetching] instead of isUser] and checked if it's true then wrote as you said.