# How to retrieve data after successful redux dispatch inside a functional component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Basically I'm trying to work out the cleanest way to retrieve the data from the state only after a redux action has been dispatched. The data in the state is only available after the action is completed, so I want to be able to access that state property after the tenant data is available in the state.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const [items, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    initialFetch();
    setLoading(false);
}, []);

const initialFetch = () => {
    // dispatches action and sets the tenant data to the state //
    dispatch(tenantActions.getAllTenants(page, perPage));

    // retrieve data from state //
    const data = store.getState();
    // DATA DOES NOT EXIST IN THE STATE BY THIS POINT //
    setData(data.tenants.items);

    // perform some functions with retrieved data //
    const cols = tableHelpers.createColumns(items);
    setColumns(cols);
}
```

My redux logger shows the request as:

```
tenants: {loading: true}
```

And the successful action response as:

```
tenants:
   items: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

So the reducer is working and sending back the data correctly.

I have tried using subscribe but it results in memory leaks. UseSelector is not possible within the function so that's also out of the question. Any advice on the best way to do with would be super helpful.

Comment: Where is your reducer?

Comment: You can use multiple `useEffect`s that run when your state changes.

Comment: If you already have the data before it is dispatched, why do you need to wait?

Comment: `setData(data.tenants.items);` is async so you can't use `tableHelpers.createColumns(items);` on the next line because `items` will not be the updated state.

Comment: "*UseSelector is not possible within the function so that's also out of the question*" - since it is a hook you should define it in the component's function body.

Comment: sorry I'll edit it to show the data doesn't exist yet, its a bit confusing

Comment: The tenantActions sets the data in the state, so I'm trying to retrieve it after its been set

Comment: I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763219/redux-dispatch-in-useeffect-isnt-syncronous)

Comment: @RameshReddy Using useSelector gives an error for an invalid hook call from within the function and it is unpopulated before the initial fetch

Comment: Set redux state in the reducer and then use mapStateToProps to get that state variable in the component. Or you can return a promise with the data from the action and access it in component with ```.then(result => {})```